# Scope in JSF Validator

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I I want to implement input filed validation. This is the code of the managed bean:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Demo Insert Form"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_databasez.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">
                    <h:form>
                        <div id="settingsdiv" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:panelGroup>Session ID</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="sessionid" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['sessionid']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="15"/>
                                        <f:validator binding="#{ValidatorController.validateMessage}" >
                                            <f:attribute name="type" value="sessionid" />
                                        </f:validator>
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="sessionidvalidate" />                                          
                                    </h:inputText>
                                    <h:message id="sessionidMessage" for="sessionid" />
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>User ID</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="userid" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['userid']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="15"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>Login Time</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="logintime" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['logintime']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>Last Refresh Time</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="lastrefreshtime" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['lastrefreshtime']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <h:panelGroup>User IP</h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="userip" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['userip']}" >
                                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="15"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                            </h:panelGrid>          

                        </div>   

                        <div id="settingstwodiv" style="width:150px; height:60px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:380px; left:800px">

                            <h:commandButton value="Create User" action="#{DatabaseController.saveData}"/>

                        </div> 
                    </h:form> 

                </div>   

            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the code that I added into faces-config.xml

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>ValidatorController</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.DX_57.HM_57.FormValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

This is the code of the Validator that I tried to test:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("ValidatorController")
@SessionScoped
public class FormValidator implements Validator {

    public FormValidator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void validateMessage(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        if (value.equals("test")) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "Session ID is already in use, please choose another.", null));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this error that I get when I try to run the example:

```
[#|2012-05-05T22:39:00.096+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgiweb|_ThreadID=58;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Removed bundle 710 against context path /test |#]

[#|2012-05-05T22:39:00.097+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=58;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Failed to deploy bundle com.DX_57.History-Module-57 [710]
org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.DeploymentException: Deployment of com.DX_57.History-Module-57 [710] failed because of following reason: Failed while deploying bundle com.DX_57.History-Module-57 [710] : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy bundle [ com.DX_57.History-Module-57 [710] ], root cause: Exception while loading the app
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiContainer.deploy(OSGiContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.deploy(JavaEEExtender.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.access$200(JavaEEExtender.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy bundle [ com.DX_57.History-Module-57 [710] ], root cause: Exception while loading the app
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.execute(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:121)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class com.DX_57.HM_57.FormValidator] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:181)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:183)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class com.DX_57.HM_57.FormValidator] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:405)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractClassBean.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:361)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.doAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanDeployment.java:216)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.afterBeanDiscovery(BeanDeployment.java:208)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:352)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:179)
    ... 17 more
|#]
```

It seems that the Validator class is not in the correct scope. What scope I have to use?

Best Wishes

Comment: Matt has answered your current problem, but you've other major mistakes in the validator as well. Fix your validator to match exactly the example in my answer on your previous question. You should be doing the job in `validate()` method of the `Validator` interface, not a custom method. You shouldn't need the old JSF 1.x `<validator>` declaration in `faces-config.xml`. You should be referencing the concrete validator instance in `binding`, not just its method.

Comment: Ok, but if I remove the declaration in faces-config.xml can I use CDI into the validator? I want to implement custom validator because if I have 20 input fields I have to implement 20 standard validators in different Java classes and files. I want to do it in one file.

Comment: Just try it? Your faces config declaration is not used in any way. It's only used on `validatorId`.

Comment: I removed from faces-config.xml the declaration of the validator. I edited the code this way: http://pastebin.com/a3GE3EL5  But when I test it nothing happens.

Comment: If you want to implement for example 20 validators how would you implement the code in order to simplify it and reduce the number of the java classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this code:

```
<h:panelGroup>Session ID</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText id="sessionid" value="#{DatabaseController.formMap['sessionid']}" 
                    validator="#{ValidatorController.validatebean}">                                        
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="sessionidMessage" />                                          
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message id="sessionidMessage" for="sessionid" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is the bean:

```
@Named("ValidatorController")
@ViewScoped
public class FormValidator implements Validator {

    public FormValidator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value.equals("test")) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "  Session ID is already in use, please choose another.", null));
        }
    }

    public void validatebean(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value.equals("test")) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "  Session ID is already in use, please choose another.", null));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know why and how but this code works! Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 10):

From the WELD documentation:

> Managed beans with scope @SessionScoped or @ConversationScoped must be
>   serializable, since the container passivates the HTTP session from
>   time to time.

There might be other reasons, but your CDI session scoped bean should at least implement the `Serializable` interface:

```
@Named("ValidatorController")
@SessionScoped
public class FormValidator implements Validator, Serializable {
...
}
```